# Pandas Dataframe to sliding window

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I have a pandas DataFrame:

| timestamp | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-27 14:05:50 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2023-09-27 14:05:51 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 2023-09-27 14:05:52 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 2023-09-27 14:05:53 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 2023-09-27 14:05:54 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 2023-09-27 14:05:55 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |

To feed it to a keras autoencoder I need a windowed version of the data (eg. window=3):

| timestamp | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-27 14:05:50 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 2023-09-27 14:05:51 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 2023-09-27 14:05:52 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 2023-09-27 14:05:53 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |

I wrote a function but I think I might miss the point. I got problems in the later process and it takes an incredible amount of time (>10 hours, on a machine with 128 cores, a lot of RAM and 32 GPU cards) on my data.

```py
def makeWindowDataFrame(df, windowSize):
    table = []
    for window in df.rolling(window=windowSize):
        if len(window) >= windowSize:
            arr = []
            for el in window.iloc:
                arr.extend(el.to_numpy().reshape(-1))
            table.append(arr)
    longest = len(max(table, key=len))
    return pd.DataFrame(table, columns=[a for a in range(longest)])
```

Is there a simpler way to create this dataset? This operation is on of the longest running in my setup.

**EDIT 1:**

```py
def win(df, N):
    return pd.DataFrame(sliding_window_view(df, N, axis=0).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(len(df)-N+1, -1), index=df.index[:len(df)-N+1])
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame( {'timestamp': {28384: pd.Timestamp('2023-09-27 14:05:50'), 28385: pd.Timestamp('2023-09-27 14:05:52'), 28386: pd.Timestamp('2023-09-27 14:05:54'), 28387: pd.Timestamp('2023-09-27 14:05:56'), 28388: pd.Timestamp('2023-09-27 14:05:58')}, 'p1l4e0': {28384: 0.8869906663894653, 28385: 0.9212895035743713, 28386: 0.9084778428077698, 28387: 0.8959079384803772, 28388: 0.9066142439842224}, 'p1l4e1': {28384: 0.3119787573814392, 28385: 0.31039634346961975, 28386: 0.3139703571796417, 28387: 0.3119153082370758, 28388: 0.30586937069892883}, 'p1l4e2': {28384: 0.9320452809333801, 28385: 0.9452565312385559, 28386: 0.9435424208641052, 28387: 0.9356696605682373, 28388: 0.9325512647628784}, 'p1l4e3': {28384: 0.10841193050146103, 28385: 0.1134769469499588, 28386: 0.11245745420455933, 28387: 0.109752357006073, 28388: 0.10924666374921799}} )

win(df, 3)
```

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28384 | 2023-09-27 14:05:50 | 0.886991 | 0.311979 | 0.932045 | 0.108412 | 2023-09-27 14:05:52 | 0.92129 | 0.310396 | 0.945257 | 0.113477 | 2023-09-27 14:05:54 | 0.908478 | 0.31397 | 0.943542 |
| 28385 | 2023-09-27 14:05:52 | 0.92129 | 0.310396 | 0.945257 | 0.113477 | 2023-09-27 14:05:54 | 0.908478 | 0.31397 | 0.943542 | 0.112457 | 2023-09-27 14:05:56 | 0.895908 | 0.311915 | 0.93567 |
| 28386 | 2023-09-27 14:05:54 | 0.908478 | 0.31397 | 0.943542 | 0.112457 | 2023-09-27 14:05:56 | 0.895908 | 0.311915 | 0.93567 | 0.109752 | 2023-09-27 14:05:58 | 0.906614 | 0.305869 | 0.932551 |

**EDIT 2:**

It seems like the index is not set. This would explain why it is not working.

```py
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df.head().to_dict('tight')
```

```json
{
'index': [28384, 28385, 28386, 28387, 28388],
'columns': ['timestamp', 'p1l4e0', 'p1l4e1', 'p1l4e2', 'p1l4e3'],
'data': ...,
'index_names': [None],
'column_names': [None]
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

After a restart of the kernel it works. A test showed that the solution gains a speedup of 1000x at minimum and 1k-10k times faster on bigger datasets. Thank you.

Comment: Just 2-3 GB only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as svw

N = 3
out = pd.DataFrame(svw(df, N, axis=0).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(len(df)-N+1, -1),
                   index=df.index[:len(df)-N+1])
```

Output:

```
                     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
timestamp                                                          
2023-09-27 14:05:50   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
2023-09-27 14:05:51   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
2023-09-27 14:05:52   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
2023-09-27 14:05:53  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
```

Output with `N=2`:

```
                      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
timestamp                                          
2023-09-27 14:05:50   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
2023-09-27 14:05:51   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
2023-09-27 14:05:52   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
2023-09-27 14:05:53  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
2023-09-27 14:05:54  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
```

##### timings

Your code is very slow for large inputs

###### on 6 rows, N=3

```
# original approach
925 µs ± 2.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# sliding window view
69.7 µs ± 266 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

###### on 60k rows, N=3

```
# original approach
6.66 s ± 57.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# sliding window view
852 µs ± 2.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

###### on 1.2M rows, N=3

```
# original approach
2min 16s ± 685 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# sliding window view
28.5 ms ± 605 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Handling extra columns:

```
N = 3
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

out = (df[df.columns.difference(cols)].head(-N+1)
       .join(pd.DataFrame(svw(df[cols], N, axis=0)
                          .swapaxes(1, 2)
                          .reshape(len(df)-N+1, -1),
                          index=df.index[:len(df)-N+1])
             )
       )
```

Comment: thank you I will try that. I think I couldn't a good solution and ended up with 'rolling'.

Comment: Rolling is not really a sliding window, its doesn't change the shape of the output. Also it's slower than numpy, especially when combined with python loops as you did ;)

Comment: I think there is something wrong. I get the timestamp repeatably as a column in the result data.

Comment: @muebau make sure the timestamp is the index: `df = df.set_index('timestamp')`, you can always reset it afterwards.

Comment: I still stuck a bit with that problem. I edited my original post as I don't know how to explain it otherwise.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input? `df.head().to_dict('tight')` But as I said, I think it's just a matter of selecting the correct columns to use in the window

Comment: I added a potential workaround (untested, I'll do it with your reproducible input)

Comment: ```
inputdata.set_index(["timestamp"])
inputdata.head().to_dict('tight')
```
```
{'index': [28384, 28385, 28386, 28387, 28388],
 'columns': ['timestamp', 'p1l4e0', 'p1l4e1', 'p1l4e2', 'p1l4e3'],
 'data': ...,
 'index_names': [None],
 'column_names': [None]}
```

Comment: @muebau please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77812013) the question with the full output.

Comment: Ok after complete restart of the python kernel (jupyter) it seems to work. I am very sorry.

Comment: @muebau no worries, glad it worked. Can you provide feedback on the timings?

Comment: first test on a small piece (1915968 rows × 48 columns) get processed in <2 sec. This is a speedup by 1000x at least. Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way: "Handling extra columns" seems to crop the result to a few rows. I use your first solution anyway. Just for completion.

Comment: @muebau indeed I hadn't tested it (as said) and `head(N-1)` should have been `head(-N+1)` (corrected).

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": [
            pd.Timestamp("2023-09-27 14:05:50"),
            pd.Timestamp("2023-09-27 14:05:51"),
            pd.Timestamp("2023-09-27 14:05:52"),
            pd.Timestamp("2023-09-27 14:05:53"),
            pd.Timestamp("2023-09-27 14:05:54"),
            pd.Timestamp("2023-09-27 14:05:55"),
        ],
        "A": [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21],
        "B": [2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22],
        "C": [3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23],
        "D": [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24]
    }
)
df = df.set_index("timestamp")
df = pd.concat([df, df.shift(-1), df.shift(-2)], axis="columns")
df = df.dropna()
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({d.index[0]: d.to_numpy().ravel() for d in df.rolling(3) if d.shape[0] == 3}).T
```

Output:

```
                     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
2023-09-27 14:05:50   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
2023-09-27 14:05:51   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
2023-09-27 14:05:52   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
2023-09-27 14:05:53  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
```